# Sentry not throwing error to the required mail

Tags: node.js, sentry

I have used [Sentry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/node) in my node backend. Here is the process

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'my address',
  // ...
});
Sentry.captureException(new Error("Something broke"));
```

Now I didn't get either any error or mail. Why I did wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you let the app terminate immediately after running those two lines?
If that's the case you likely killed the process before it had a change to flush (send to sentry) the event in its internal queue.

The docs describe the process of [Shutting down and draining the queue](https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/configuration/draining/?platform=node).

Comment: Thank you. I will let you know if needed more help.